# A fast way to write Pandas dataframe data into existing .docx document table

Tags: python, pandas, ms-word, docx, python-docx

I need to write dataframe data to existing table in Word Document. The table in the document already has two rows, and I need to add df rows after those 2 rows. Using `python-docx` library.

```
document = Document(docx=document_name)
table = document.tables[0]
for i in range(orders.shape[0]):
    table.add_row()
for i in range(orders.shape[0]):
    for j in range(orders.shape[1]):
        table.cell(i + 2, j).text = str(orders.values[i,j]) 
document.save('xxx.docx')
```

This script works well, but it's took very long time: it needs 10 seconds to write 1 row. If dataframe has 5000 rows, it's a problem. Anybody knows faster way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Start by avoiding repeated row and column lookups with something like this:

```
values = orders.values
for i in range(orders.shape[0]):
    row = table.add_row()
    for j, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
        cell.text = str(values[i, j])
```

and see how much improvement you get.

Comment: Like x10 faster. But still slow:)

Comment: What timing figures have you gathered? Next step would be to create the table all at once rather than adding rows. That will mean you need to create the top two rows yourself rather than extending an existing table.